# Typesafe: API Rate Limit Exceeded for

Tags: typesafe-stack

Trying Typesafe stack templates from Getting started Guide

http://typesafe.com/resources/typesafe-stack/downloading-installing.html

For below command I get error "API Rate Limit Exceeded for my_ipaddress"?

```
$ g8 typesafehub/play-scala
This template generates a Scala play 2.0.X project (verbatim means exclude files from parsing) 
verbatim [*.html *.js]:
application_secret [CHANGEME12345678]:
application_name [my_app]: tutorial_play
play_version [2.0.2]: 
dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response code: 403
{"message":"API Rate Limit Exceeded for <my_ip_address>"}
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$when$1.apply(executor.scala:53)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$when$1.apply(executor.scala:50)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$x$2.apply(executor.scala:41)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$x$2.apply(executor.scala:36)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:54)
    at dispatch.Http.pack(Http.scala:25)
    at dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.execute(Http.scala:53)
    at dispatch.Http.execute(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.x(executor.scala:36)
    at dispatch.Http.x(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.when(executor.scala:50)
    at dispatch.Http.when(Http.scala:21)
    at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(executor.scala:60)
    at dispatch.Http.apply(Http.scala:21)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(apply.scala:123)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(apply.scala:123)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:104)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$opt$1.apply(Exception.scala:104)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:104)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$write$1.apply(apply.scala:122)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$write$1.apply(apply.scala:115)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at giter8.Apply$class.write(apply.scala:115)
    at giter8.Giter8.write(giter8.scala:3)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$inspect$1.apply(apply.scala:35)
    at giter8.Apply$$anonfun$inspect$1.apply(apply.scala:21)
    at scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277)
    at giter8.Apply$class.inspect(apply.scala:21)
    at giter8.Giter8.inspect(giter8.scala:3)
    at giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:22)
    at giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:16)
    at giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:3)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:54)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:43)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:68)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:14)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:25)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:15)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response code: 403 {"message":"API Rate Limit Exceeded for <my_ipaddress>"}
```

What this error mean & How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try again later. Maybe you downloaded too many projects!

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the Github API. You have exceeded their [API rate limit](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-10-14-rate-limit-changes/) through g8:

> Unauthenticated requests will be limited to 60 per hour

g8 used the Github API internally, you may have used g8 more than 60 times during one hour.